# Pass data to default.ctp (layout file) from random controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, layout, indexing, set

I am simply trying to pass data from my controller to my default layout file:

users_controller

```
$this->set('fish', 'trout');
```

default.ctp (layout file)

```
echo "You caught a " . $fish. " from the river.";
```

What I am trying to achieve is: echo $group['Group']['name']; in the default layout file, but the above was my first attempt to understand how the relationship actually works.

Thanks for any advise on this : )

Answer (score 2):

anything that you set to the view is available in the layout.

Comment: How would I go about calling in a specific record criteria for example: echo $group['Group']['name']; ? For example Groups has columns: id, name. And I need to get the name echoed out. I tried the above ( $group['Group']['name']; ) and does nothing. Do I need to create a foreach in the layout?

Comment: pr($group) see what the structure is

Answer (score 1):

If you set anything in the default.ctp, it will show in the layout just like you would do in a view. There's no difference.

You might not be seeing anything because you have set debug to `0` and you have an error. Try making it `2` and check it out.

Comment: I am trying more tests and it still is not working. For example, I just entered this into my layout with a valid Tree model call: <?php 
 
 $this->set('trees', $this->Tree->find('all')); 
 
 foreach($trees as $tree):
 
 echo $tree['Tree']['name'];
 
 endforeach;
 
 ?>

Comment: My debug is and has been set at 2. I am aware of this functionality. I tried again in my default.ctp, and yes the error message is: Undefined variable: trees. So the it seems it needs to be set() or compact() in the controller, but I have yet to get this working : (

Answer (score 1):

As Thorpe says, you need debug set to non-zero.

Check (and change) in `app/core.php` (search the file for debug and you'll see the information you need).

If you're not getting any output this is most likely the problem.

debug($aVar); is IMO more useful than `echo` or `pr` as it will output the line number even if there is no other output (but you *must* have debug enabled!).